# Merging several comments into an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette

Let's say I ask a question on Stack Overflow, and I get several comments with bits and pieces of information, but no answer.

In the end, all these comments sum up to enough information to have an answer. Is it okay for me to merge all the information from the comments to write a single answer?

Answer (score 6):

Yes of course. You are free to answer your own question (in an answer) and use all available information, including but not limited to comments. Please note, that comments fall under the same license as all the other content, so attribution must be given (a link to a comment is hidden under the greyed time stamp of the comment).

This is even encouraged, because comments are second class citizens, may be deleted at any time and don't allow to fully vote on them. You do the community a service by combining comments into an answer.

Caveats: The information should really be enough to provide an answer. If the comment explicitly states that it will be expanded into an answer by the commenter soon, I would wait a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine. Either if you do it or anyone else does it.

You can also mention that you got the needed information from the comments, but since in the end by the time you post the answer the comments will be obsolete and deletion would probably be the better course of action, giving attribution is hit-or-miss here.

You can give attribution linking to the comments, but soon enough the links will be stale... (because either you or someone else can flag the comments as "no longer needed", since what they say has been incorporated in a post).

Also, attribution is required if you are quoting content. If you rephrase the knowledge you got from the comments in your own words (and even better, expand on it with additional research), attribution is not **required**, although it's polite to credit your sources.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, of course it's fine! You can, optionally, add a note that you have formed your answer from information given in comments, as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574270/10871073) - following some very helpful advice given by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in his [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572896/if-statement-not-working-in-c-section-within-if-statement-always-runs/59574270#comment105315058_59572896) to the question.